# Can we add private data collection to a channel in existing network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Can we add private data collection (PDC) to an existing network without restarting the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we can.

- PDC can be added when you upgrade your chaincode.Dont forget to add
  the pdc defination file.

Comment: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private_data_tutorial.html this would help you out.Please see the flags used  in peer chaincode install command